# How to Printing tuple without parentheses?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print tuple in python 2 without parentheses and in it should be printed in same line. How it to print it?

Comment: x = ("foo", "bar")
print "{} {}".format(x[0], x[1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just this?

```py
tup = ('Hello', 'world')
print(', '.join(map(str, tup)))
```

Comment: How can I do output formating while printing using above syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
t = (object1, object2, ...)
print(*t, sep=',')
```

This should work for any type of items present in the tuple. For example :

```
>>> t = ([1,2], (2,3), 7, 'j')
>>> print(*t, sep=',')
[1, 2],(2, 3),7,j
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
tup = (1,2,3,4,)

for t in tup:

    t = list(t)

    t = t[0] 

    print(t)
```